# Installing Crystal Reports runtime with InstallShield 2013 LE

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports, installshield, redistributable

I am trying to make a setup for my program by using InstallShield 2013 LE and I am running it from within VS 2012. I have already downloaded and installed .NET 4.5 as one of the prerequisites under Specify Application Data -> Redistributables.

[image]

My application has reports that I made by installing CRforVS_redist_install_64bit_13_0_8 from the site http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824.

The reports and program run well. I know that I need to include the crystal reports runtime as part of my setup for deployment to other computers. 
Under Specify Application Data -> Redistributables, I see Crystal Reports Basic for Visual Studio 2008. How do I add the right runtime version that I need to my program?

[image]

Also for some reason, I am unable to download even the 2008 version shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InstallShield Limited edition lacks the prereq editor found in Professional and above.  You can download an eval and throw it on a VM and use it there.  Correct the PRQ file and copy it back to your ISLE machine along with needed content.

Here's a basic tutorial on how to author PRQs:

[Using InstallShield 12 to Install .NET Framework 3.0](http://blog.iswix.com/2006/11/using-installshield-12-to-install-net.html)

Comment: Thanks for yor reply Christopher Painter. I will do as you suggest.

Comment: FWIW, I recently did a crystal reports prereq for a customer.  The business objects download was in a ZIP (or similar)  and had to be extracted.  This means it wasn't suitable as a web download location unless you self host it somewhere else.